# CAML Query with Contains and Or Clause Issue

Tags: sharepoint, wss, caml

What I want to achieve : Take a keyword array as input and query Sharepoint List to return all rows which contain the keywords in the list.

I have built a simple CAML query to query my list with one keyword (pdf) .

```
<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Keyword'/><Value Type='Text'>pdf</Value></Contains></Where></Query>
```

This works fine.

But, when I try to use Or clause in the CAML query(see below), I get the following error

"One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."

```
<Query><Where><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='Keyword'/><Value Type='Text'>pdf</Value></Contains></Or></Where></Query>
```

I googled for the syntax and everything looks good. Please let me know what is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you using SharePoint 2007there might even be one out there for 2010) i recommend you try to use CAML builder will make your life easier!

Comment: Truezplaya, unfortunately..there are restrictions downloading softwr in my company. I am only consuming the lists service in sharepoint from my Javascript and won't bee needing it in future. Is there a online tool to evaluate the syntax?

Comment: Unfortunatly i don't think there is. The tool would improve efficiency when writing CAML so i would have thought you would have a good case to get a copy. If you writing CAML once i am sure you will come across it again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CAML Query if you want to use OR you must and should have 2 conditions.

Comment: The number of keywords could be 1-n . I am building the Where clause dynamically. So, as I understand, I need to exclude OR clause if there is one keyword and include it if there are more than one ?

Answer (score 0):

The field reference name must be the internal name. You can find this by going to the colmn page in list/library settings and the name is the end of the URL. Spaces and underscores in the name must be handled differently.